# Loading BIG JSON with d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, treemap

I have a custom Treemap which loads JSON file from a remote server. I've always loaded small files (e.g. 50Kb) with the following function:

```
d3.json("/assets/json/jhd.json", function(root) {
...
}
```

Today I experimented my implementation with a bigger file (30Mb) but in this case the root variable of the previous function is `null`. As a consequence my implementation crashes.
Any suggestion or recommendation?

You can see the JSON file here: http://atelier.inf.usi.ch/~romanelm/download/jhd.json

```
...
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"149529","name":"isSameClassifierRoles","value":500},
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"152175","name":"createStackedActivations","value":500},
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"157591","name":"isIncoming","value":500},
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"162929","name":"initialize","value":500},
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"211226","name":"setFilled","value":500},
{"type":"MethodModel","id":"232389","name":"hasIncomingCallActionFirst","value":500},
...
```

Comment: Have a look at [this interesting article](http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/). Couldn't you split your large json into several json objects and make partial calls to get all the data and then reassemble it on the client side?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @NicolaeOlariu. I'll consider that as a "Plan B" option. :-)

Comment: Try remove the white space for your json file or consider the "Plan B" now

Comment: Have you tried displaying the error?

Comment: @ChristopherChiche the error is `Cannot set property 'y' of null` because `root` is null

Comment: @jhyap I did that and now the file is "just" 8MB but the problem is still there

Comment: I mean the error issued by d3.json (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your JSON file, and it's certainly not too big for D3.js to handle. Check your dev console for HTTP errors on the GET. Also, are you sure you're not trying to access `root` outside of the callback?